# Eclipse Java multiple-instance conflicts?

Tags: java, multiple-instances

I am running multiple instances of my own chess algorithm in Eclipse, having them play games against themselves.  Each instance of the main class plays games against itself, so if I start two instances of the main class, two chess games will be played simultaneously.  The two games should not conflict.  However, I am getting unusual results.  One instance is consistently winning.  The other is consistently losing.  Both main classes reference a number of other static classes.  When multiple instances of the main class are running, do they share other static classes?  Is it possible that one could conflict with the other, or affect its results?

Comment: No static fields are shared between Java processes.

Comment: Is there any other way to explain my results?  Could it be caused by patterns in Math.random()?

Comment: There's too many factors to say for sure, especially without seeing any code.

Comment: It's just occurred to me: what are you counting as a "win"? If each process plays a game with *itself*, the only potential winner *is* itself.

Comment: Are the instances of the main class actually in different processes from launching more than one, or are they living in the same JVM?

Comment: This question is far to difficult to answer without a deep dive in the code itself.

Comment: The code itself shouldn't matter.  I'm clicking the run button in Eclipse two times in a row, and neither instance is reading external files, so they should produce the same results.  They are playing hundreds of games, so I would expect any use of Math.random() to even out.

Comment: @nitind, each instance shows up as a separate process in task manager, so I believe they are in separate JVMs.

Comment: Most of the time, it *is* your code's fault in some way.

Comment: With whom are the processes playing? Against each other? How are they communicating, is there any mediator betwen them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, different JVMs running at the same time do not have anything in common, and don't conflict with each other.